# MenuItem Trigger not working

Tags: .net, wpf, triggers, menuitem, resourcedictionary

I want to use a `trigger` to automatically hide a `MenuItem` which is disabled. If I use my style inside a particular `MenuItem` like this it works -

```
<MenuItem
    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, 
                        Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.ExportCommand}"
    Header="Export...">
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
</MenuItem>
```

but if I place the same `style` in a `ResourceDictionary` like this, then it doesn't work -

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type MenuItem}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I want to have this behavior for all my menu items and I don't want to put this style on every `MenuItem` inside my `ContextMenu`. Any Idea why it's not working?

Comment: Is it working for inside MenuItems if you place the Style into ContextMenu.Resources?

Answer (score 1):

Style is automatically applied to all instances of target types only if it does not have `x:Key` set (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx). Is this your case?

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, but that's not the case. I have tried without x:Key too. For your info(from the link you provided) - **Relationship of the TargetType Property and the x:Key Attribute**
 

_As shown in the first example, setting the TargetType property to TextBlock without assigning the style an x:Key causes the style to be applied to all TextBlock elements. **In this case, the x:Key is implicitly set to {x:Type TextBlock}**. This means that if you explicitly set the x:Key value to **anything other than {x:Type TextBlock}**, the Style is not applied to all TextBlock elements automatically._

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. I have just tried it:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="{x:Type MenuItem}" TargetType="MenuItem" >
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>

</Grid.Resources>

<TextBox Text="Hello!" IsReadOnly="True">
  <TextBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu >
      <MenuItem Header="Item1" />
      <MenuItem Header="Item2" IsEnabled="False"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Item3" />
    </ContextMenu>
  </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
</Grid>
```